# WebRTC connection to TURN sequence

Tags: networking, webrtc, turn, coturn

Is it possible to connect WebRTC peers to different TURN servers and then establish the connection between TURNs?

So each peer connected to its own TURN server and then these TURNs connecting to each other

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this isn't a problem at all!

For a TURN allocation you really have two entry points. The Server and Relay listener.

WebRTC for the Curious also has a visualization [here](https://webrtcforthecurious.com/docs/03-connecting/#turn-usage)

[image: Two TURN Allocations visualized]

Comment: How can this be represented with code? Or this architecture works by default?